# MVC4 Solution for duplicate form field names

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

In creating a form with a model that has contained objects. 
Most of them have an Id field.

If you use @Html.HiddenFor() to display those fields then
they all have the same name as Id.

We tried using @Html.Hidden() and supply a unique name such
as "ApplicantId" or "AddressId".  But then the Id properties
are not set on the model when it gets back to the controller.

So the question is how to using @Html.Hidden() with custom
names and make them map back to the correct field when submitting
the form?

```
public class PersonView {
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

We want to use

```
@Html.Hidden( "ApplicantId", Model.Id)
```

But then the framework doesn't map the ApplicantId form field to the PersonView.Id field when it gets back to the controller.

This makes sense because the name ApplicantId doesn't match any of the properties on the PersonView object.
Is there perhaps an attribute to decorate the PersonView.Id property to indicate a more unique name?

Comment: Please post some of your c# classes which has the  `Id` properties and how they relate to each other!

Comment: @nemesv  Added code snippets.

Comment: Please post your entire ViewModel. I think is better to fix you root problem, not try to force the framework accept different IDs to do the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you use @Html.HiddenFor() to display those fields then they all
>   have the same name as Id.

What you are experiencing should be related with other issues.
If you have one ViewModel with several properties, each property is an object with a property called "Id", when you place it in a form using the helpers (in the XXXFor() form at least) the input id became: "`YourPropertyName_Id`" and "`YourOtherPropertyName_Id`".

When you post a complex model (model that contains other models as properties) you need to instanciate the properties in a parameter-less constructor, in the viewmodel. The model binder will call it and then populate its properties. ***That could be the reason of not receiving the ids on post.***

The ID of your inputs can be overrided for what you need to use in Javascript... but it is not used to do the model binding, the framework uses the `name` attribute for that, not the `id` (BTW, the `name` attribute is formed similar to the `id`, but with a `.` instead of `_`, so it end like `YourPropertyName.Id`).

Comment: Oh you're saying that it's not necessary to provide unique names to avoid binding collisions.  Okay..we'll try it that way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank. You're right. It's handled just fine by the helper methods. Wow. Very cool. Thanks again.